# How to download a file for specific users

Tags: php, header, external

I use code like that shown on the first part below to download a file from an external site that isn't mine. The token is required and if it isn't valid the download fails. I want to duplicate that action with my own site. I have control over both the sending and receiving servers but can't get this to work. Would someone explain what I am doing wrong, please?

Here is the code on the sending server:

```
    $url = "https://example.com/download/index.php?token=$someid";

    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '1'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
    curl_exec($ch);

    try {
        if(curl_errno($ch)){
            throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); } 

    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($statusCode == 200) {
      handle the downloaded file
    } else {
      echo 'Result = '. $statusCode; 
    }
```

And this is on my site (the receiving server). The true is just for testing so when I execute the above code I should get a 404 but it just shows "Result =".

```
    if (true || ! empty($_GET['token'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    } 
    header("Location: http://example.com/myfile.zip");
    exit;
```

Comment: whats with the ` in  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, \`); ` where are you defining `$someid`?

Comment: Sorry - bad edits. The line is in since I don't use SSL locally so I set it to 0 or 1 depending on where the script is ran from. I have changed that for this example.